# For or foreach to display two variable

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli

I stuck with the simplest problem for beginners, and after all day of coding i don't see where is the problem.. i try a for and foreach() loop but right i need advice and help.. 
ok, i have a table friends in database with id, name, lastname and age.
i did the query -> simple one

```
  $friends =mysqli_query($db, "Select * from FRIENDS");
  while($fri = mysqli_fatch_array($friends));
  echo $fri['id'];
  echo $fri['name'];
  echo $fri['lastname'];
  echo $fri['age'];
```

it show two friends with

```
id  name lastname age
1   mark marcus   23
2   luke dark     24
```

i need to show only the ages in seperate variable and affter that i will use easy if else to compare who is older and who is younger.

Comment: You have obviously transcribed this from your actual code. Please always copy/paste your real code to avoid typos ("fatch" vs "fetch") and misunderstanding the actual problem.

Comment: Please clarify what do you expect to happen if in the table there are: a) no rows , b) exactly 1 row, c) 3 or more rows. The solution depends greatly on what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: Goal is to show only last two rows and grab age from them

Comment: @Lima  you have only two records in table? or you have more records?

Comment: I have more but I will display only last two.. (by SQL and limit 2) and try to compare who is older and younger.

Comment: @Lima  check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the query returns exactly two rows, you can assign them to named variables, like this:

```
$rowYounger = mysqli_fetch_array($friends);
$rowOlder = mysqli_fetch_array($friends);
if ($rowYounger['age'] > $rowOlder['age']) {
    // Wooopsie, I guesed wrong!
    // Let's make up for that lil' blunder at swap the variables:
    [$rowYounger, $rowOlder] = [$rowOlder, $rowYounger];
}
print 'Younger: ' . print_r($rowYounger, true);
print 'Older: ' . print_r($rowOlder, true);
```